# SQL Server 2012 - SSAS Deployment Failed: File System Error, Access is Denied

Tags: deployment, ssas, access-denied, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

The context is OLAP cube development. After configuring my project though SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT, the new BIDS) I am unable to deploy the project.

Every time the deployment process is started I get an error like the one below:

> File system error: The following error occurred while opening the file '\\?\D:\[...]\database\mssql\tmpdb\MDTempStore_1864_9_no8wd.tmp': Access is denied.

(The [...] denotes some part of the path I ommited for brievty)

I always get the same error, indicating that some .tmp file could not be accessed.

My environment:

- **OS**: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, SP1
- **SQL Server**: SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.2100.60), running on localhost

What I tried:

- I have the File System access rights for the folder in question (at some point I even tried with Admin privileges on the machine, didn't help)
- I tried to deactivate the anti-virus in case it was performing on-access-scan (still didn't help)
- Attempts to deploy/process individual dimensions causes the same problem
- Deploying dimensions or cubes programmatically through SMO (instead of SSDT) runs into the same problem
- Deploying DataSource objects as well as DataSourceView objects works fine

Maybe some of you faced similiar issues or have further suggestions/ideas?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out.

As expected it was a permission issue, but despite the error message hinting at some missing file system permissions, the cause of the problem was the user I configured the Data Source with.

The SQL User I specified was given the roles

- db_datareader
- db_datawriter
- db_ddladmin

on the source database but this doesn't seem to be enough. When I tried to give him the server role *sysadmin* it started working.

This is probably overkill, one could further fine-tune the role assignment but for now it also works that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion here - have you tried running SSDT as an administrator? That is, right-click on SSDT and click Run As Administrator. Then try to deploy your project. It definitely sounds like a permissions issue.

Comment: hey Stacia, thanks for the quick answer. I tried running SSDT as an administrator but it didn't help :(

Comment: I've never seen anything like this before, for whatever that's worth, and I've worked with SSAS a very long time. The next thing I would try is to create a new project, add in the DS and DSV objects from the first project, and create a shell dimension object. Just create a dimension using the primary key attribute and try to deploy/process to   see if the problem can be isolated to your first project or if it's universal. If that works, then pull in one of your DIM objects into the new projet and try to deploy/process to see if problem can be isolated to something in your dimension objects.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had the same idea and already tried this. As stated in the "What I tried list", deploying DataSource and DataSourceView objects works fine. The problem arises when deploying dimensions. An interesting fact is that, when programmatically creating a dimension, I am able to create it and the error then only arises when I attempt to process it.
Maybe the problem is a Database Engine one? But why does it arise when the Analysis Services try to process some object then?

Comment: I saw that you had tried deploying DS and DSV, but didn't know if that was in separate project. Those objects aren't going to be much help though by themselves. They get called into action when you do the processing of a dimension or a cube. You could have a DB engine problem. It would only arise during processing because that's when the SQL statement to get data for the dim or cub is executed. Another thought - if it's at all possible - is to uninstall and reinstall SSAS.

Answer (score 0):

Exact reason is SSAS Service user does not have an access to the folders that are specified in SSAS configuration (i.e error states it is Temp Folder). I think it is not directly related with SQL Server because it is just a file access error. Error is thrown before it reaches SQL Server.

Give full permission to SSAS Service User for those folders.

Regards
Onur